# URLSession dataTask does not run

Tags: swift

I am having a problem with this block of code. I am testing my app using Network Link Conditioner under the "very bad network" profile and under the condition of a user having a poor internet connection, this dataTask never runs. If the connection is good this code works fine. I'm guessing it doesn't run because the connection is bad, but how can I handle this scenario, since I cannot get a response from the completion handler as the line never runs?

```
let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
                    do {
                        print("RUNNING RECEIPT UPLOAD TASK")
                        if let jsonObj: [String : AnyObject] = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions(rawValue: 0)) as? [String : AnyObject] {
                            if let resultData: [String : AnyObject] = jsonObj["result"] as? [String : AnyObject] {
                                if let status: Bool = resultData["status"] as? Bool {
                                    if status {
                                        completion(status, nil, resultData)
                                    } else {
                                        if let errorMessage: String = resultData["message"] as? String {
                                            completion(status, errorMessage, resultData)
                                        } else {
                                            completion(status, "FAILED RECEIPT UPLOAD", resultData)
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            } else {
                                completion(false, "FAILED RECEIPT UPLOAD", nil)
                            }
                        } else {
                            completion(false, "FAILED RECEIPT UPLOAD", nil)
                        }
                    } catch _ {
                        completion(false, "FAILED RECEIPT UPLOAD", nil)
                    } 

                })

                task.resume()
```

If I try testing for an active internet connection before running this using Reachability or the following block of code, it will return true even when there is a connection but it is poor, so I cannot handle the dataTask not running by testing for a connection first.

```
static func isInternetAvailable() -> Bool {
        var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in()
        zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: zeroAddress))
        zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

        let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(to: &zeroAddress) {
            $0.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) {zeroSockAddress in
                SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, zeroSockAddress)
            }
        }

        var flags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags()
        if !SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability!, &flags) {
            return false
        }
        let isReachable = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsReachable)) != 0
        let needsConnection = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired)) != 0
        return (isReachable && !needsConnection)

    }
```

Comment: You can set request timeout for the request... and after timeout show message to user like poor internet connection or something.

Answer (score 4):

> I'm guessing it doesn't run because the connection is bad, but how can I handle this scenario, since I cannot get a response from the completion handler as the line never runs?

You should simply accept that you might not get a response from the completion handler. That is the whole point of asynchronous operation: you might get a response soon, it might take a long time, it might be never. Your code should be written in such a way as to deal with that.

By default, when you make a URLSession, its configuration's `waitsForConnectivity` is `true`. You should *not* use Reachability to learn whether there is connectivity; you should just start the task and stand back. The task will happen when it can.

However, if that is not acceptable and you need to fail early, then set the configuration's `waitsForConnectivity` to `false`. You will then fail with a timeout, probably in one minute (the default).

It should also be pointed out, however, that you are sort of shooting yourself in the foot by using a data task with a completion handler. That is a very limiting approach. It would be much better to give the session a delegate and implement the delegate methods, so as to receive full information as to what is happening as it happens.